# GTD tool for Mac OS X and iPhone?

Tags: macos, iphone, gtd

I am looking for a GTD (getting things done) tool, which there is a OS X and an iPhone app available. I don't want any web based stuff, but native applications. The Mac application needs some functionality for synchronization with the iPhone app.

Are there any GTD apps, which fit my requirements?

Comment: Interested in GTD? Join [Personal Productivity and Organization](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4296/personal-productivity-and-organization-gtd-covey-etc), we are looking for users & experts... :)

Answer (score 5):

I use [Things](http://culturedcode.com/)

Comment: Things looks and works nice, but a huge drawback (dealbreaker for me) is that the synchronization requires you to open the app on both your iPhone and Mac, and have them be on the same network just to synchronize items. And even that typically doesn't work in my office environment.

Answer (score 3):

My understanding is that OmniFocus is literally a GTD implementation and it has an iPhone app.
I use Things as my to-do list which syncs over wifi (same network) with its iPhone app.

For productivity, the [Pomodoro technique](http://www.pomodorotechnique.com/) seems to be getting popular. There is a new book, [Pomodoro Technique Illustrated](http://pragprog.com/titles/snfocus/pomodoro-technique-illustrated), from the [Pragmatic Programmers](http://pragprog.com/). There are some mac apps to use with it including [Pomodoro Desktop](http://pomodoro.ugolandini.com/). I am not sure about iPhone apps, but the technique primarily relies on a 25 minute timer and every iPhone can do that.

**UPDATE:** There are several free and paid iPhone apps for the Pomodoro technique including  [Pomodoro Timer](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pomodoro-timer/id325610693?mt=8) (iTunes Link).

Answer (score 2):

I use [OmniFocus](http://www.omnigroup.com/applications/omnifocus/).

Answer (score 0):

**Informant** for the **iPhone** has a task list that is switchable to the **GTD** style. i'm really loving it, but i'm also an avid **Google** calendar user. **Google** also has a task list in beta in their calendar. so far the tasks are not yet subscription based so i can't see my **Google** tasks on my **iPhone** **Informant** calendar, and i can't see my **GTD** tasks created in **Informant** on **Google** calendar. i'm sure its only a matter of time.

the great and powerful thing about **Informant** is that it gives you an interface almost identical with **Google** calendar, especially the month view. i love love love it.

i'm sure eventually they'll get the task's synced and then your **Getting Things Done** problem will be solved.

by the way, i also use **Things** on the **iPhone**--it is a spectacular task list app. it is my favorite, but does not yet integrate with **Informant** or **Google** calendar. someday soon i hope. i have contacted them.

Answer (score -1):

I like [Remember The Milk](http://rememberthemilk.com) and [Evernote](http://evernote.com).

Comment: As both of these tools are not specifically meant for GTD, it would be helpful for you to explain how they integrate with GTD.